# Não consigo executar procedure no PHP - Fatal Error na linha do execute( )

Tags: php, sql, oracle, pdo, procedure

Não consigo executar uma procedure pelo PHP, na hora de mandar o execute do PDO exibe o erro da imagem, na minha base oracle a procedure executa normalmente.

Tentei fazer com que exibisse o erro do SQL mas fracassei

Segue trecho do meu código:

```
if ($pdo = conectar()) {
    $last_nunota = $pdo->prepare("SELECT NUNOTA FROM TGFCAB WHERE 
                                NUNOTA = (SELECT MAX(NUNOTA) FROM TGFCAB)"); //definindo nº unico TGFCAB
    $last_nunota->execute();
    $array_nunota = $last_nunota->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $nunota = $array_nunota['NUNOTA'];    
    $nunota++;
    $next_nunota = $nunota;


    $last_numreq = $pdo->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT AD_NUMREQ FROM TGFCAB WHERE
                                AD_NUMREQ = (SELECT MAX(AD_NUMREQ) FROM TGFCAB)"); //número requisição
    $last_numreq->execute();
    $array_numreq = $last_numreq->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $numreq = $array_numreq['AD_NUMREQ'];
    $numreq++;
    $next_numreq = $numreq;

    $insert_cab = $pdo->prepare("EXECUTE STP_INSERE_REQUISICOES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");      //insert na cab

    $insert_cab->bindValue(1, $next_nunota, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $insert_cab->bindValue(2, $next_numreq, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $insert_cab->bindValue(3, $obs, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $insert_cab->bindValue(4, $codcencus, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $insert_cab->bindValue(5, $codnat, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $insert_cab->bindValue(6, $codtop, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $insert_cab->bindValue(7, $codparc, PDO::PARAM_INT);

    $insert_cab->execute();
```

--abaixo segue minha procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE TESTE.STP_INSERE_REQUISICOES(
           P_NUNOTA         NUMBER,
           P_NUMREQ         NUMBER,
           P_OBS            VARCHAR,
           P_CODCENCUS      NUMBER,
           P_CODNAT         NUMBER,
           P_CODTOP         NUMBER,
           P_CODPARC        NUMBER)

   AS

           V_DHTIPOPER     DATE;
           V_TIPMOV        VARCHAR2(1) :='J';
    /****************************************************************
    *   Objetivo: Inserir requisições de PRODUTOS OU SERVIÇOS       *
    *   para o portal de requisições instalado na Intranet.         *
    *   Autor: Jeiel Rodrigues Silva                                *
    *   Data: 01/03/2019                                            *
    ****************************************************************/          
   BEGIN
        -- Pegando informações atualizadas da TOP
        SELECT 
                TOP.DHALTER, 
                TOP.TIPMOV        
        INTO
                V_DHTIPOPER,
                V_TIPMOV  

        FROM TGFTOP TOP
        WHERE TOP.CODTIPOPER = P_CODTOP
        AND TOP.DHALTER = ( SELECT MAX( TP.DHALTER )
        FROM TGFTOP TP
        WHERE TP.CODTIPOPER = P_CODTOP);


        INSERT INTO TGFCAB(
            AD_NUMREQ,
            NUNOTA,
            AD_OBSERVACAOINTERNA,
            AD_RCLIBERADA,
            AD_RCVERIF,
            AD_CONFORME,
            CODEMP,
            CODCENCUS,
            NUMNOTA,
            DTNEG,
            CODEMPNEGOC,
            SERIENOTA,
            CODPARC,
            CODTIPOPER,
            DHTIPOPER,
            TIPMOV,
            CODTIPVENDA,
            DHTIPVENDA,
            CODVEND,
            CODPARCREDESPACHO,
            COMISSAO,
            CODMOEDA,
            CODOBSPADRAO,
            VLRSEG,
            VLRICMSSEG,
            VLRDESTAQUE,
            VLRJURO,
            VLRVENDOR,
            VLROUTROS,
            VLREMB,
            VLRICMSEMB,
            VLRDESCSERV,
            IPIEMB,
            TIPIPIEMB,
            VLRDESCTOT,
            VLRDESCTOTITEM,
            VLRFRETE,
            ICMSFRETE,
            BASEICMSFRETE,
            TIPFRETE,
            VLRNOTA,
            CODPARCTRANSP,
            QTDVOL,
            PENDENTE,
            BASEICMS,
            VLRICMS,
            BASEIPI,
            VLRIPI,
            ISSRETIDO,
            BASEISS,
            VLRISS,
            APROVADO,
            STATUSNOTA,
            IRFRETIDO,
            VLRIRF,
            DTALTER,
            CODPARCDEST,
            VLRSUBST,
            BASESUBSTIT,
            CODPROJ,
            NUMCONTRATO,
            BASEINSS,
            VLRINSS,
            VLRREPREDTOT,
            PERCDESC,
            CODPARCREMETENTE,
            CODPARCCONSIGNATARIO,
            CODNAT,
            TROCO,
            CODUSUCOMPRADOR,
            CIF_FOB,
            CODCONTATO,
            CODUSU,
            CODUSUINC)
        VALUES (
                P_NUMREQ, --AD_NUMREQ
                P_NUNOTA, --NUNOTA
                P_OBS, --OBSERVAÇÃO INTERNA
                'N', --AD_RCLIBERADA
                'N', --AD_RCVERIF
                'N', --AD_CONFORME
                1, --CODEMP
                P_CODCENCUS, --CODCENCUS
                0,--V_NUMNOTA, --NUMNOTA
                sysdate, --DTNEG
                1, --CODEMPNEGOC
                1, --SERIENOTA
                P_CODPARC, --CODPARC
                P_CODTOP, --CODTIPOPER
                V_DHTIPOPER, --DHTIPOPER
                V_TIPMOV, --TIPMOV
                0, --CODTIPVENDA
                '01/01/1998', --DHTIPVENDA
                0,  --CODVEND
                0, --CODPARCREDESPACHO
                0, --COMISSAO
                0, --CODMOEDA
                0, --CODOBSPADRAO
                0, --VLRSEG
                0, --VLRICMSSEG
                0, --VLRDESTAQUE
                0, --VLRJURO
                0, --VLRVENDOR
                0, --VLROUTROS
                0, --VLREMB
                0, --VLRICMSEMB
                0, --VLRDESCSERV
                0, --IPIEMB
                'N', --TIPIPIEMB
                0, --VLRDESCTOT
                0, --VLRDESCTOTITEM
                0, --VLRFRETE
                0,  --ICMSFRETE
                0,  --BASEICMSFRETE
                'S', --TIPFRETE
                0, --VLRNOTA
                0, --CODPARCTRANSP
                0, --QTDVOL
                'S', --PENDENTE
                0,
                0,
                0,
                0,
                'N',
                0,
                0,
                'N',
                'L',
                'S',
                0,
                SYSDATE,
                0,
                0,
                0,
                0,
                0,
                0,
                0,
                0,
                0,
                0,
                0,
                P_CODNAT,   --CODNAT
                0,
                0,
                'S', /*CIF_FOB SEM FRETE*/
                null,
                0,
                0
        );

   END;
```

Comment: Olá Jeiel, seja bem vindo! Após a conexão `new PDO()` insira `$pdo->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING );` e depois do `[..]$pdo->prepare[..]` insira `print_r($insert_cab ->errorInfo());` que irá mostrar o erro

Comment: Resolvido Andrei, muito obrigado!

Comment: Opa! Sem problema!